# Unable to refresh the cache of IE browser

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I am trying to log in into my webpage in IE browser, the problem is that it allows user to login but the headers and the interface made for login account does not shows up instead previously cached data is shown...and when i refresh the page then only user is able to see the new data for log in member...i am using spring and angular java script.
webpage works fine in other browsers.
 thanks in advance

Comment: javascript != java. Set the meta "expiration"

Comment: @Jonasw The java tag here is probably to accompany the spring tag.

Comment: * it works fine if developer tool is kept on in IE browser......

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5000; URL=http://yoururll.org/"> this reloads the page all 5000s

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara : however, java is not relevant to the question

Comment: I did tried to reload the page if the session is not null..i.e. it will ensure that somebody has made successful login but the problem occurred is that now page will check for session which is not null so it keeps on reloading..... i am really stuck!!!

Comment: please post your code...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 var flag=true;
   var session_obj1= '<%=sess1%>';
   var session_obj2= '<%=sess2%>';

       if(session_obj1!='null' || session_obj2!='null' && flag)
         {
         
               window.location.reload();
           
          flag=false;
         }
    }); 
</script>
here i am reading the session object value and reloading if found

Comment: This question really needs some love. Provide more information: what you are trying to do (and why - maybe there is a better solution that one you think of), how your JSPs look like etc. Other people are using their time to help you out so you could use some of your time as well and prepare a good question.

Answer (score 0):

If your using ajax to load the data then you need "cache: false" in IE.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data:data,
                success: function (result) {

         }               
  });
```

Comment: <div ng-switch on="currentUser.role" ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}">
<div ng-switch-when="uploader"><div ng-include="'templates/headers/header2.html'" ></div></div>
<div ng-switch-when="viewer"><div ng-include="'templates/headers/header2.html'" ></div></div>
<div ng-switch-default ><div ng-include="'templates/headers/header.html'" ></div></div>
</div>
this is how i am changing the login headers...

Comment: Thankyou...
but got this solved by using
the below code...........


mymodule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};    
    }    

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
}]);

Comment: That's great @Vinay Mittal